# Construct a diffeomorphism $\psi: B_1 \to \epsilon\text{-neighborhood of } K$, where $K$ is a subset of a smooth manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm currently working through a paper by Brezis on the topology of Sobolev spaces. Right now I am having trouble understanding the following note made by Brezis.

> Let $M$ be a compact and smooth manifold and $K \subset M$. Then there exists a diffeomorphism 
>   $$\psi: B_1(0) \to \epsilon\text{-neighbourhood of } K$$
>   (where $B_1(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\dim M = n$).

Does it have to do with $K_\epsilon$ being an open subset of the smooth manifold $M$ and thus a smooth manifold itself? Does that already imply the existence of such diffeomorphism? I am a little confused right now.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: What's the paper?

Comment: Topology of Sobolev Spaces (http://www.mat.ufpb.br/jmbo/papers/Brezis/brezis/breli01.pdf), p.337 after the proof of proposition 1.5.

Comment: Well the author only says "Suppose that we are able to construct a diffeomorphism..." He's not claiming that one always exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is not claiming that such a diffeomorphism always exists. For instance, if $K = M = S^1$ or $M = S^1\times S^1, K = S^1 \times \{0\}$, then it is clear that no neighborhood of $K$ can be homeomorphic to an open ball.

Comment: $B_1(0)$ need not be an open ball, but it is an open nbd (I guess)

Comment: @Anubhav From the paper: "$B_1$ is the unit ball centered at the origin in some Euclidean space."

Comment: but do you think if I consider $B_1(0)$ as an open nbd, then is it true?

Comment: I've just looked again at the applications of the Proposition mentioned above. Indeed, the diffeomorphisms needed are all trivial. Thanks!